# The D+J programming challenge from Kattis

Tags: python, algorithm, math, equation-solving

The problem is as follows:

> Dick is d=12 years old. When we say this, we mean that it is at least twelve and not yet thirteen years since Dick was born.
>
> Dick and Jane have three pets: Spot the dog, Puff the Cat, and Yertle
>   the Turtle. Spot was s years old when Puff was born; Puff was p
>   years old when Yertle was born; Spot was yy years old when Yertle was
>   born. The sum of Spot’s age, Puff’s age, and Yertle’s age equals the
>   sum of Dick’s age (d) and Jane’s age (j). How old are Spot, Puff,
>   and Yertle?

The input's given are s,p,y,j and the output required is: spot's age, puff's age and yertle's age.

**My solution was as follows:**

```
import sys
import math

d = 12
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = [int(x) for x in line.strip("\n").split()]

    s = line[0]
    p = line[1]
    y = line[2]
    j = line[3]

    yertle = (d+j-y-p)/3.0
    difference = yertle - math.floor(yertle)
    if difference > 0.5:
        # for the 0.66666 cases
        spot = puff = int(math.ceil(yertle+p))
        yertle = int(math.floor(yertle))
    else:
        # for the 0.33333 cases
        yertle = int(math.floor(yertle))
        puff = yertle + p
        spot = d+j - puff - yertle

    print spot,puff,yertle
```

but it is incorrect on certain inputs such as: s=5, p=5, y=10, j=10. Because for those specifications the actual age's of the dogs are: spot=12.333, puff=7.333, yertle=2.333 but because we are doing integer division we get 12,7,2 instead. However, those results don't satisfy the $$spot + puff + yertle = dick + jane$$ 
rule. Does anyone have other ideas on where I am making a mistake or how i should've approached/solved this?

P.S. [link for problem source](https://open.kattis.com/problems/dickandjane)

Comment: spot=13.000, puff=7.333, yertle=2.333 satisfy inputs s=5, p=5, y=10, j=10. The actual age difference between Spot and Yertle is y + [0,1)

Comment: @hk6279 But isn't the difference between Puff and Yertle similarly, p + [0,1). In which case, we could say spot=12.333, puff = 8, yertle=2.333, right? How do we know to add the 0.6666 to spot and not puff or yertle?

Comment: The same rule apply to (Puff and Yertle) and (Puff and Spot). But spot=12.333, puff = 8, yertle=2.333 is incorrect because 12.333-8 = 4.333.

Comment: @hk6279 Ah, I see what you mean. I tried to account for that in the newer version of my code (now pasted in the question). It, for example, correctly returns 8 8 6 on the inputs 0 1 1 10 (as it should right?) But I'm still getting a wrong answer verdict. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use float arithmetics, work with integers.

Let's denote `D+J = DJ`, Spot's age `S`, Puff's age `P`, Yertle's age `Y`

Let's  Spot birthday time is zero, so Puff was born in interval `[s, s+1)`, Yertle was born in interval `[y, y+1)`. Current time is in interval `[S, S+1)`.

[image]

If we look onto time line, we can see that

```
   S = y + Y
   or
   S = y + Y + 1
and 
   S = s + P
   or
   S = s + P + 1
```

age sum is

```
 DJ = S + Y + P = S + S - y + S - s - (0, 1, 2)
```

where (0,1,2) is possible addendum

```
 3 * S = DJ + y + s + (0,1,2)
```

We can see that right part **must be divisible** by 3, so next calulations depends on value

```
 M =  (DJ + y + s) modulo 3

case M = 0: (5 5 10 9)
     S = (DJ + y + s) / 3 = (21 + 15) / 3 = 12
     P = S - s = 12 - 5 = 7
     Y = S - y = 12 - 10 = 2

case M = 1: (5 5 10 10)
     here we should add 2 to make sum 37 divisible by 3
     S = (DJ + y + s + 2) / 3 = (22 + 15 + 2) / 3 = 13
     P = S - s  - 1 = 13 - 5 = 1 =  7
     Y = S - y  - 1 = 13 - 10 - 1 = 2

now more complex case M = 2 (5 5 11 10):
    here we should add 1 to make sum 38 divisible by 3 
    and solve - where use 1 - for P or for Y calculation?
    We can determine this evaluating s/p/y relation:
    if y = s + p + 1 then use 1 for Puff's age else for Yertle
    (because Puff's fraction is larger then Yertle's fraction, 
    she was born in the later year period)
    here 11 = 5 + 5 + 1, so
    S = (22 + 16 + 1) / 3 = 13
    Y = S - y = 13 - 11 = 2
    P = S - s - 1 = 13 - 5 - 1 = 7
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! Could you please elaborate on the last case, the one titled 'now more complex case...'; like where did the y = s + p + 1 identity come from, and I noticed you compute S first before Y, whereas I've been computing Y first, does this make a difference?

Comment: Imagine that Spot was born in Jan 2000, Puff in October 2005, and Yertle in Feb 2011. s=5, y=11 and p=5! In May 2013 we have Puff age 7 (while 2013-2005=8). Added some comment in answer.

Comment: I tried implementing your algorithm and it worked! But please answer this for me: does it matter that you are solving Spot's age first and solving Y and P in relation to it? Because I was solving for Yertle first and solving S and P in relation to Y.

Comment: I've composed equation for Spot because it seemed simpler for me. If you can make simple and correct approach for Y first - use it.